# Objects moving to the left in a simulation of objects being attracted to each other

Tags: python, pygame

I made a python program that simulates objects (particles) attracting each other like in the space with pygame.

However, they all move to the left instead of going to the center...

What should be modified to make the particles attract the right way?

The code works by calculating the velocity of every particle with their gravitational force by looping in every particle and then calculating its velocity by looping again in every particle and calculating the velocity between those 2 particles.

Code:

```
import pygame
import math
import time

particleMass = 1
res = 10

fps = 60

G = 6.674 * 10 ** -11

multi = 10 ** 7.5

size = (700, 700)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

particles = []
velocities = []

red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

x = 0
y = 0


for _ in range(res ** 2):
    particles.append([-size[0] / 2 + x * (size[0] / res),-size[1] / 2 + y * (size[1] / res)])
    velocities.append(0)

    x += 1

    if x == res:
        x = 0

        y += 1


def norm(pos):
    return [pos[0] + size[0] / 2, pos[1] + size[1] / 2]


def moveParticles(pos1, pos2, vel1, vel2):
    dist = ((pos1[0] - pos2[0]) ** 2 + (pos1[1] - pos2[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5

    force = (G * particleMass ** 2) / dist ** 2

    vel21 = ((2 * G * particleMass ** 2) / dist) ** 0.5
    vel22 = ((2 * G * particleMass ** 2) / dist) ** 0.5

    angle1 = math.atan2(pos1[0] - pos2[0], pos1[1] - pos2[1])
    angle2 = math.atan2(pos2[0] - pos1[0], pos2[1] - pos1[1])

    resPos1 = [pos1[0] + (vel21 * multi - vel1) * math.cos(angle1), pos1[0] + (vel21 * multi - vel1) * math.sin(angle2)]
    resPos2 = [pos2[0] + (vel22 * multi - vel2) * math.cos(angle2), pos2[1] + (vel22 * multi - vel2) * math.sin(angle2)]

    return resPos1, resPos2, vel21, vel22


def calculatePoses(poses, velo):
    clear(black)

    resPoses = poses[:len(poses)]
    resVelo = velo[:len(velo)]

    for i in range(len(poses)):
        for j in range(i):
            resPoses[i], resPoses[j], resVelo[i], resVelo[j] = moveParticles(poses[i], poses[j], velo[i], velo[j])

    return resPoses, resVelo



def clear(color):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(0, 0, size[0], size[1]))


def draw(lst):
    for pos in lst:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, pygame.Rect(norm(pos)[0], norm(pos)[1], size[0] / res / 5, size[1] / res / 5))


while True:
    start = time.time()

    clear(black)

    particles, velocities = calculatePoses(particles, velocities)

    print(particles[0], particles[1])

    draw(particles)

    pygame.display.update()

    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    if 1 / fps > time.time() - start:
        time.sleep(1 / fps - time.time() - start)
```

The objects are attracted to the left instead of being attracted to the center like they should.

Comment: You have stated a problem. What is your question ([ask])? Have you tried any [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to narrow down the source of the problem? Do some hand-calculations with a simplified problem -- start with two objects and check if their velocities are calculated correctly by your code. Then check if those velocities are translated into their new positions correctly. If all this is correct, add a particle and repeat. Once you've found the specific part of your code that's wrong, you can think about how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

this happens because (0,0) is the top left of the window u have coded it to go to (0,0) so it goes to top left of the window.

change the calculations and adjust it depending on the size of your window

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with the way you are computing the gravitational interactions, you loop like this:

```py
for i in range(len(poses)):
   for j in range(i):
```

which means that each particle will only be affected by particles before it in the position list. Because your particles are ordered from left to right (because of how you build the initial positions grid), each particle will be more affected by particles to its left, and so be pulled in that direction.

You need then to make sure that each particle is affected by all other particles. The naive solution would be to fix the loops to:

```py
for i in range(len(poses)):
   for j in range(len(poses)):
    if i==j:
      continue
    # compute positions
```

But as you have ~10k points, look into scipy pairwise distance computation to speed things up: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html